# Alias in where query in SOQL

Tags: salesforce, soql, salesforce-lightning, salesforce-service-cloud, salesforce-communities

I am trying to take the count from the object **Lead** using SOQL.
When I am hitting the below mention query, I am getting the results.

```
select 'Lead' as source_table,count(*) as source_count from Lead
```

But when I am trying to give `where` condition with this query, then it is throwing me the error.

> select 'Lead' as source_table,count() as source_count from Lead where
>   CreatedDate > 2020-02-24T09:43:51Z

Is there anything that I am missing.

Answer (score 0):

Your query is not a valid SOQL, where exactly are you doing it? In real Salesforce (Apex, developer console, Salesforce APIs) or do you work on some copy of data imported to MSSQL for example?

Even your basic form (`select 'Lead' as source_table,count(*) as source_count from Lead`) will not parse OK in SOQL. There's no `AS` keyword and no dummy columns.

Closest would be

```
SELECT COUNT(Id) source_count
FROM Lead
WHERE CreatedDate > 2020-02-24T09:43:51Z
```

There will be no artificial column with "Lead" in it. If you need some key-value thing across multiple database tables you'd have to process results in Apex, maybe make a helper class to store results, maybe a `Map<String, Integer>` would be enough. But if you're doing it as API access then much better idea would be to access the dedicated APIs

- [getUpdated REST API](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_rest.meta/api_rest/resources_getupdated.htm) - has "updated" and "deleted" versions, if you really need "created" it's not that great unless you filter them out later somehow
- [record count across multiple objects](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_rest.meta/api_rest/resources_record_count.htm) - but it's really count in table, similar to Setup -> Storage Usage. No way to pass a WHERE clause
- ask your SF admin to build a report that does what you need (you don't need details, just a count, right?), then access the results with Analytics API. Or even build the report on the fly: [example](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_analytics.meta/api_analytics/sforce_analytics_rest_api_get_reportdata.htm)

Comment: My this query "select 'Lead' as source_table, count(*) as source_count from Lead" is working properly by this I am getting 2 columns one is Source_table another is sink_table and on that, I am getting lead in a source table column and count in sink_table column but when I use where condition in that then it is not working. I am hitting this query by Azure data factory and wanted to load this in a SQL table in that table I will be having 2 columns Source_table and Source_count.

Comment: "source_table", "sink_table"? Are you doing some integration? Mulesoft, Informatica, Azure Data Factory, that kind of stuff? It really reads like your question is not about Salesforce but about MSSQL or Oracle SQL or any other non-SF database system. Your syntax is not valid in SF. If you have on-premise database you'll have to work with the SQL flavor it can understand.

Comment: I am fetching data from salesforce using azure data factory and using data factory I am Hitting query to Salesforce cloud objects.

Comment: The query you posted seems to be running against SQL Server database that happens to have Lead table, with data fetched from SF. You need SQL Server syntax then, not SOQL (unless you want to retrieve from SF only leads created after certain date). Retag the question and hopefully some SQL server guru will help you?